# Trying to write an If statement that will show date of last item selected and change as updated

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a series of data. That goes down the left side column of dates...
8/2, 8/3, and such. Then 2 columns over I have a column left for if the date is checks       so  8/2:X, 8/3:X, 8/4: ,8/5: and such.   I'm wanting to reference the date in the last field that has a X in it

```
A   B C D
8/1     X
8/2     X
8/3     x
8/4
8/5
```

Trying to reference the date for the last A cell if there is an X in the D cell. So it would be for 8/3 would be the date. I'm not sure how to run with this.

I've looked through but now sure how to state an if statement

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your sheet?

Comment: [link](https://i.postimg.cc/d0w6s4gV/2019-08-28-13-14-59.jpg)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do here. You want your formulas to only calculate if there's an X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want you cells to calculate if there's an X in column E you could write it like this:

`=if(E3="x","", [put your calculation here] )`

If you only care if there's anything there, not necessarily an "x" or if you're worried about case sensitivity:

`=if(isblank(E3),"", [put your calculation here] )`

Then just drag this formula down.

**Based on what you had told me use the following formula in cell `H1`**:

`=maxifs($A$3:$A$24,$E$3:$E$24,"x")`

Comment: Ok, so  my formula is in H1 and reads as =IF(E6="x",A6,A5), but that will give me if there is an X in A6, and says if there is not an x in the E6 field then use the previous. But i'm basically trying to use the Date from the last E cell with an X in it.

Comment: @PantheonEngineeringDesigns I added the solution to my answer

Comment: for whatever reason that maxifs formula isn't saying its a function for me.

Comment: The version of Excel you have may not have that function yet, in that case the other solution will work fine, but over very large ranges may hang up the system for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

To return the date in column A that is in the same row as the last "X" (or "x") in column D:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(D:D="X"),A:A)
```

Comment: interesting that 1/(D:D="x") is a range/lookup vector.  My mind does not naturally think like that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to return the highest date with a X in it right? You can simulate a MAX IF with array formulas:

```
{=MAX(IF(E:E="X",A:A,FALSE))}
```

(You have to enter the formula with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER to get those brackets and to it work properly)

The IF part inside that formula returns only a list of values (inside the TRUE part) that the condition returns true

Edit: If you're using Excel 2013 and above, you should check @Mark answer, as it is a cleaner way to do it

Comment: No need to nest a max formula into an array like that for this.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that in your sheet you're using a lowercase X, you can either change the formula to that or change in the sheet

Comment: @MarkS.I'm not sure when was maxifs added, but without that formula, the only way I know to simulate it, is with an array

Comment: Yeah, but now it exists so there's no need, but maybe its a version thing. Do you have the function? If not, which version are you using, @j. paulo

Comment: @MarkS. I'm on 2010 Office. It seems that maxifs was added in 2013, and by the looks of what OP posted, he should have that formula available. If so, maxifs is definitively the better way

Comment: Okay so that's where the cutoff is at 2010, but make no mistake, I've done your method a number of times, and for the case of `MEDIAN` this is still the best method. I just shy away from Array formulas since they sometimes can have unexpected results for inexperienced users (like being unable to clear a single cell in the array if the do the `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` with everything highlighted rather than carrying down.

Answer (score 0):

Just going to throw my hat in the ring here for a formula that will display the value of date that corresponds to the largest row number with an X in it in column D.

AGGREGATE will find the row number as follows:

```
 =AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(D:D)/(D:D="x"),1)
```

That can be nested inside an INDEX function to return the cell address of corresponding date which in turns display the value of the cell as follows:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(D:D)/(D:D="x"),1))
```

While the above does work, AGGREGATE is performing array operations.  Therefore full column references like D:D should be avoided and reduced to a smaller range that would closer match your data in order to avoid excess calculations on blank cells.

Answer (score 0):

> If you can **ONLY** enter the `X` **consecutively** without skipping a date, for instance you would not mark `8/6` **X** if `8/5` has no **X** marked, then you can find the last date using the following formula:

```
=INDEX(Column_Date,COUNTIF(Column_X,"X"))
```

The look up is **case insensitive** which means you can also enter lowercase `x` instead of uppercase `X` in column D or mix them up, the formula will return the same result anyway.

The solution is using **COUNTIF** function to locate the position of the last `X` in Column E of your worksheet, and then use **INDEX** function to return the corresponding date in Column A.

**COUNTIF** is a combination of **COUNT** and **IF** function. I guess this might be the "IF" function you are after.

Please note if the `X` is not marked consecutively day by day, you may need to use someone else' answer.

Cheers :)